# 'Flag as inappropriate' notification system - is there a gem or plugin for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to implement a 'flag as inappropriate/abusive' notification system for my app, whereby users can click an icon or link if they think a post/comment is inappropriate, and a notification email is then sent to the site admin. Are there any gems/plugins for this kind of functionality (Rails 3)? Or if I need to roll my own, would using a taggable gem (eg. acts_as_taggable or similar) be suitable for this purpose? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [can_flag](http://github.com/courtenay/can_flag) plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, that's definitely the kind of thing I'm after although Rails 3 compatibility might be an issue...

Comment: Yes, It's true, there's no Rails3 support (yet) for `can_flag`, by the way I do not remember another gem/plugin to flag content =/.

Comment: Sonia, did you ever do the legwork on getting this compatible for rails 3?